# Type error: 'property does not exist on type' when it in fact does exist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting an error during the build process (Vercel) with `product` that's passed into `CartItem.tsx` even though it's declared in `types.tsx`.

The error:

```
Type error: Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type 'Product'.
  43 |       <div className="flex items-center">
  44 |         <Image
> 45 |           src={product.imageUrl}
     |                        ^
  46 |           alt={product.itemName}
  47 |           width={100}
  48 |           height={100}
```

**CartItem.tsx:**

```
import { Product } from "types/types";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function CartItem({ product }: { product: Product }) {
/* ... */

  return (
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <Image
          src={product.imageUrl}
          alt={product.itemName}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full mr-4 object-cover"
        />
       {* ... *}
      </div>
  );
}
```

**types.tsx:**

```
/* ... */
export type Product = {
  id: number;
  restaurantId: number;
  itemName: string;
  restaurantName: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  // title: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  // discountPercentage: number;
  // rating: number;
  // stock: number;
  // brand: string;
  // category: string;
  // thumbnail: string;
  // images: string[];
  quantity?: number;
};
```

Comment: Is that the right location? The code in the error differs from `CartItem.tsx` which suggests it appears somewhere else. The code presented shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: @Anton It is, sorry, got rid of some of the code for className when cleaning up. I've put it back. Yeah it shouldn't. I'm perplexed.

Comment: Is that import statement right tho? Shouldn't it be something like `"./types/types"`. If you hover `Product`, what is the type definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've written there it should work. I would try moving your type definition to the same file as `CartItem` temporarily to see if that resolves the problem - if it does then there must be a problem with how your type is imported.

Also a side note: you can use the type React.FC to more cleanly type components.

```
type CartItemTwoProps = { product: Product };

const CartItemTwo: React.FC<CartItemTwoProps> = ({ product }) => {
    return (
      product.imageUrl // works
  );
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcATAVwzgF44BvcuOMGYAuOADtWIAEZIoFAUQDOMFKygoxMAJIjxkmXP6CYSEADkUIJKOVRgYgOby4SlWo0wLVmzDuPnoCgOSACqUAA2Pn5ORgD0sXAwwDDh1nC29jECzEiKaHZgSRBiUZnOYHZoaRLSss7xcMzAeRCsmgyyVZpB1fp1cQnqSY6iNQb1CcoQaADWo32GAg1S6mK6Gf4DcGgoJg7Q1KWbSwkwABb6YijAkem%20ZVuBwYpHDgDaALrOAI6sHsnUAD881qhgAvhRyJg2hhgMU4ABhFCwLQmEAACh4cAqEDYHDBoixOLxMFETFx7HgYIAlLwjAokDA1GI4Oj6QJsSxKQA6J6hCJwBoAd2gM0URmpFDBlBodERyO0aIAKiLyWBFFxeJyKRgyVz8ZC0MVlPKUcqRaJkOgYNyAGIIgA8SLNphVEDVigAfJrMdqSXAaVxvXwOS5GczWeyBMSeXywuFBQkRVAxRKpUA)